# Tapping TFS Checkin Event

Tags: tfs-sdk

I am working on project to  implement some check-in policies in TFS at server side . As part of this,  I am trying to get the history of the changeset now  being committed. But when check in happens, I get changeset number as -1. I dont' know why this happening. I doubt whether the changeset number is assigned only after the ProcessEvent method is executed. Appreciate your help.

```
public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType,
              object notificationEventArgs, out int statusCode, out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
           {
               statusCode = 0;
               properties = null;
               statusMessage = string.Empty;


               if (notificationType == NotificationType.DecisionPoint)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       if (notificationEventArgs is CheckinNotification)
                       {
                           CheckinNotification notification = notificationEventArgs as CheckinNotification;


                              int changeId = notification.Changeset;; // here I get the Changeset as -1
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
```

Answer (score 5):

You're not going to be able to get the current changeset number, as the policies are executed before the changeset is committed.

It has to do it this way so that it can deny the checkin if the policy is violated.  If the checkin is denied, it shouldn't increment the changeset number.